# What's the alternative for hta (HTML apps)?

Tags: html, hta

I have to convert a HTML application (.hta file) so that it can be executed on Linux and MAC also.

What could be the alternate ways of doing it? Should I convert to an AJAX app?

Any suggestions? OR Has anyone gone through this before?

Reagards,
/Syed

Comment: I'd say that largely depends on what the HTA does. If it's extremely Windows specific it may not be portable to another system at all, if it's basically just a website with Javascript it may run with minimal modifications in any other browser...

Comment: No its not Windows based app. It has to run on Linux, MAC also. Actually, there is a link on a page and when user clicks on it, browser provides a pop up to either run it (if IE) or save the .hta file (if FF, Safari, Chrome). In latter case, a user has to open the file and run it manually from the location where it was downloaded. Then it shows up the interface where a user chooses which clouds apps to be installed.

Comment: One way which I have figured out, I shall convert it into asp.net app. So that the first pop window will not be dependent on platform and the user will not have to save .hta file first in order to see that.

Comment: HTA is one way on Windows via IE to allow XmlHttpRequest across any domain w/o cross domain restrictions for a local HTML-based file. I'd be interested in how you can do same (local HTML + JS based file making XHR requests) on Linux and Mac w/o resorting to plugins like Flash/AIR or server side scripting or complicated JS code workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Though you have not provide the nature of application. I mean what you application does.
What I get from question is since you are using HTA application that means you application requires system level access. Now since Linux and windows are completely different platforms. It is not possible to complete port one app from one platform to another.

If you can work at the plugin level like development of flash-plugin or you can use the Adobe AIR to build your application.

I mean to say don't use Microsoft native code in you application.

Comment: Thank you Saruabh for your suggestion. But I completed the task by upgrading the application to ASP.NET application. It is working fine and is very stable.